# What is the default location of Docker seccomp profile?

Tags: docker, seccomp

**Question:**
Where does docker store it's default seccomp profile ?

It seems like this isn't documented anywhere(at least i couldn't find it) . What i could find was the contents of the file on github: https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/profiles/seccomp/default.json .

**Context:**

I currently have two docker hosts and one container which i want to run.
The container worked on one host but did not work on the other.
After some debugging and searching online i found out how to make the docker run on the other host as well this can be achieved by adding `--security-opt seccomp:unconfined`

This solved the issue i had. Now i want to know the exact difference between the docker seccomp profiles and therefore i would like to know where the seccomp profile of docker is stored.

OS: Ubuntu Server 16.04

Working Docker Host: `Docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec`

Failing Docker Host: `Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be`

Answer (score 1):

I think the content of default.json is compiled into binary [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/profiles/seccomp/default_linux.go). And
actually the [default.json](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/profiles/seccomp/default.json) file itself is generated using this: https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/profiles/seccomp/generate.go to create a base/example for the users, see the comments in the source code:

> // saves the default seccomp profile as a json file so people can use it as a
> // base for their own custom profiles

Answer (score 0):

I've tracked down similar issues by using `strace`. Make sure `strace` is installed in the image or install it temporary in a running container. When running the container make sure to start with `--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE` to allow syscall tracing. Also you might want to run `strace` with `-f` to follow forked processes.

Do the host run different versions of docker?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer yes they are running two different version, I added them in the original question. Regarding using strace this a possibility and i will use it if there is no easy way to look at the profile. But I want to see all the differences so i can make sure i won't have additional problems in the future with different containers. OTH just updating both hosts to a newer docker might be the faster and better option.